# Facilitate Multiple Django Files

Tags: django

There's multiple builtin files in Django.

```
views.py models.py url.py settings.py wsgi.py
```

It's frustrated to shift around.

To use them effectively, one can try to create projects in repeated times.

How can a newbie get used to functions of all the files in a short run?

or how to organize them in mind

Comment: Are you asking about how to create them more easily or how to modify them all at once with a text editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just asking how you can keep multiple files open in a project, use a decent text editor like Sublime, Atom, Visual Studio Code, etc. They all support multi-file editing.

If you're asking about how to picture a Django project in your head, you can mostly ignore the `settings.py`. The heart of any Django app is the `urls.py`. It acts as a set of "endpoints" that the browser can call and whatever URL matches will call it's related view in `views.py`. That view then handles the incoming browser request and decides what model to load from `models.py` and which template to pass the data (context) to.

```
browser -> urls -> view -> template
               |     ^
               |   model
               |
               `-> view2 -> template2
                     ^
                   model2
```

This is what's called a ["Model View Controller" (MVC) pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Django names them slightly differently, which can be confusing; Django calls a controller a "view" and a view a "template".

Comment: Why django intro books not use this diagram?

Comment: Could I ask what kind of tool you use to draw the diagram?

Comment: @YumiTada no tool, it's just ascii characters (text) in a code block that I wrote by hand. Code block's are monospace so the characters all line up.

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py startproject mysite
python manage.py startapp myapp
```

[this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project) is what you need.